# Facebook not selecting expected image from a link

Tags: facebook

I insert the URL of a test link into the FB debugger.  The output of the debugger does not show the image that I expected to see.  It shows an image which is similar to the default FB profile image but not exactly the same.  I'm not sure exactly where this image is coming from.  Anyway, here's a code snippit taken from the code that the FB scraper sees:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var payload = {"title":"Web App","cajaHtml":"\u003cmeta property\u003d\"og:image\" content\u003d\"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-YRW6ArxFx2E/VW9zPVAH-gI/AAAAAAAALU4/9W2HxXCLKkA/s360/P6030123.JPG\"
```

The value of the 'content' parameter is, in fact, the URL of the image that I was expecting to see.  I see the image that I am expecting to see when I point my browser directly to the link.  Can anyone offer any possibilities as to the reason why that image that i was expecting to see is not being associated with my FB link?  Thanks for any input.

```
... doug
```

Comment: _“Can anyone offer any possibilities as to the reason why that image that i was expecting to see is not being associated with my FB link?”_ – because you did not put proper Open Graph meta tags into the HTML source of your page, but instead are trying to insert them with JavaScript, which the Facebook scraper doesn’t bother with …?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The thing is that the particular link involved is a Google Apps Script (GAS) which uses the HTML service.  Under this arrangement the entire head element is somehow provided, i thought by GAS althoiugh I haven't got a clue as to how it would know to add the OG meta tags.  Cutting to the chase, is the bottom line of all this that we can't expect that FB will associate meaningful images with links that are written in GAS using the HTML service?  Thanks.